# DataOutputStream, does it lose some bits

Tags: java, networking

I'm writing a client server application, but I don't receive the same bytes at the client side when they are sent from the server side.
At the server side I used `.write(bytes[])` method. At the client side, I used `.readFully(byte[])` method. 
Do you have any idea ?

The sent code:

```
     System.out.println("Server got connection from " + connectionFromClient.getPort());
        in = connectionFromClient.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = connectionFromClient.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);
        LicenseList licenses = new LicenseList();
        String ValidIDs = licenses.getAllIDs();
        System.out.println(ValidIDs);
        Encryption enc = new Encryption();
        //byte[] dd = enc.encrypt(ValidIDs);
        byte[] dd = enc.encrypt(ValidIDs);
        String tobesent = new String(dd);
        //byte[] rsult =  enc.decrypt(dd);
        //String tt = String(rsult);
        System.out.println("The sent data**********************************************");
        System.out.println(dd);
        String temp = new String(dd);
        System.out.println(temp);
        System.out.println("*************************************************************");
        //BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(out));
        dataOut.write(ValidIDs.getBytes());
        dataOut.flush();
        System.out.println("********Testing**************");
        System.out.println("Here are the ids:::");
        System.out.println(licenses.getAllIDs());
        System.out.println("**********************");
```

The client Side:

```
         Socket connectionToServer = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7050);
        InputStream in = connectionToServer.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);

        int available = dis.available();
        byte[] data = new byte[available];
      //  dis.readFully(data);
        dis.read(data);
        System.out.println("The received Data*****************************************");
        System.out.println(available);
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println("***********************************************************");
```

Comment: Can you give an example of some bytes that you sent and what you received instead?

Comment: Can you post code that does the writing & readin?

Comment: You've said below that this is for a class project. Please use the `homework` tag in future for that sort of thing. It helps people to help you better by correctly targeting their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contract of `in.available()` does not guarantee anything. See the excerpt from the API below:

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

Your code basically rely on / assume that all data sent, will be available immediately and reported accordingly by `in.available()`.

To make sure you get all data, you could, on the sender side, start by sending an integer, telling how many bytes will be sent:

```
dataOut.writeInt(theBytes.length);
```

and then on the receiver side use that integer when creating the array:

```
byte[] data = new byte[dis.readInt()];
```

---

Does the bytes you send come from a `String`? In that case, you should be careful with the charset. The sender and receiver might have different default charsets.

You could for instance use `str.getBytes("UTF-8")` and `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` to be sure the receiver interprets the bytes the way the sender intended.

Comment: well this app is only for a class project, both the client and the server apps are running on the same machine (my computer )